# Rotation-sensitivity of SVD

Tags: svd, compression, rotation

Suppose I perform a truncated SVD on a symmetric, PSD matrix $A \in R^{N \times d}$ (lowering the dimensionality from $d$ to $k$). Further suppose that there is a rotation matrix $Q$ such that some of the rows in $A$ are given by applying $Q$ on another subset of the rows (I.e some rows are rotation of the others).

Intuitively, this rotation-based dependency can be used to more efficiently compress $A$ into $k$ dimensions. Under which conditions the SVD would use this fact and “implicitly discover” the rotation?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what a "truncated" SVD is?  One meaning is that you retain *all* nonzero singular values; another is that you retain only the $k$ largest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No SVD decomposition is not sensitive to these kind of dependencies.  Consider for example a diagonal matrix with two groups of rows having the same set of eigenvalues. Those groups are related by some rotation (since the rows in each group are orthogonal and the set of magnitudes is the same), but the SVD truncation will just pick the $k$ largest eigenvalues of the entire matrix, regardless of whether they are duplicated or not.